# Subtracting VBA Variables

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have an Access front end with SQL tables and procedures. I have tried to figure out the best we to get a message box telling the user how many records were added via the SQL Procedure.

```
Private Sub cmdAddReconciliationRecords_Click()
  reccount1
  AddReconciliationRecords
  Reccount2
End Sub

Public Sub reccount1()
  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim Rec1 As Integer

  Set db = CurrentDb
  Rec1 = DCount("*", "dbo_reconciliation")
  msgBox Rec1 & "Records" 'I will take this out once I get it to work
End Sub
```

'Then the Procedure AddReconciliationRecords runs appending records

```
Public Sub Reccount2()
  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim Rec1 As Integer
  Dim rec2 As Integer
  Dim tot As Integer

  Set db = CurrentDb
  rec2 = DCount("*", "dbo_reconciliation")
  tot = rec2 - Rec1
  msgBox tot & " records added."
End Sub
```

The results I'm getting is the total number of records instead of the difference between the record number I started with and the record number I ended with.
Thank you all for your help.

Comment: In the second sub, you never initialise `Rec1`so by default it's 0 so you are always doing `rec2 - 0`.

Comment: Why not just have `AddReconciliationRecords` tell you how many records it inserted?

Comment: Never mind, i figured out the answer literally 5 minutes after posting this and i have been working a day on figuring out how to get the record count of appended records.

Comment: Thanks litelite, That's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had to put them in the same Sub and it worked. Sorry, I'm new to this stuff.

```
Private Sub AddReconciliationRecords()
Dim oConnStr As String
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim recSet As ADODB.Recordset
Dim recSetStr As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim Rec1 As Integer
Dim Rec2 As Integer
Dim Tot As Integer

Set db = CurrentDb
    Rec1 = DCount("*", "dbo_reconciliation")
    msgBox Rec1 & "Records"

'*****blocking server info

Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConn.Open oConnStr

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = oConn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "AddReconciliationRecords"
cmd.CommandTimeout = 300

cmd.Execute

oConn.Close

Rec2 = DCount("*", "dbo_reconciliation")
Tot = Rec2 + -Rec1
msgBox Tot & " records added."
```

End Sub